# Why can't I set a css attribute to my array. Coding for Hangman Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why can't character.setAttribute() work. If you delete the line, the 
format of what I am trying to accomplish is there, but the CSS for the letters don't make it invisible. If I do put the setAttribute() in, the code doesn't work.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
}
ul {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

.boxes {
font-size:1.6em;
text-align:center;
width: 10px;
border-bottom: 3px solid black;
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var possibleWord = ["cow", "better", "harder", "justify", "condemn", 
"control", "hello", "understand", "life", "insight","date", "righteous"];
var hangmanWord = possibleWord[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
possibleWord.length)];
var underlineHelp;
var space;
var guess;
var guesses = [];
var placement;
var underscores;
var character = [];
window.onload = function () {
placement = document.getElementById('hold');
underlineHelp = document.createElement('ul');
placement.appendChild(underlineHelp);
for (i = 0; i < hangmanWord.length; i++) {
underscores = document.createElement('li');
underscores.setAttribute('class', 'boxes');
guesses.push(underscores);
underlineHelp.appendChild(underscores);
character = document.createElement('li');
character = document.createTextNode(hangmanWord[i]);
character.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');//The issue is here, if you take 
//this line out then the format will be correct, except I am trying to hide 
//the letters with the css attribute "hidden."The dashes are represented by 
//the bottom-border of "boxes." 
underscores.appendChild(character);
}
</script>
<div id = "hold"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TextNode` doesn't have attributes.

```
character = document.createElement('li');
character = document.createTextNode(hangmanWord[i]);
```

I am guessing you want to do:

```
character = document.createElement('span');
character.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hangmanWord[i]));
character.classList.add('hidden');
underscores.appendChild(character);
```

Working example:

```js
var possibleWord = ["cow", "better", "harder", "justify", "condemn",
  "control", "hello", "understand", "life", "insight", "date", "righteous"
];
var hangmanWord = possibleWord[Math.floor(Math.random() *
  possibleWord.length)];
var underlineHelp;
var space;
var guess;
var guesses = [];
var placement;
var underscores;
var character = [];
window.onload = function() {
    placement = document.getElementById('hold');
    underlineHelp = document.createElement('ul');
    placement.appendChild(underlineHelp);
    for (i = 0; i < hangmanWord.length; i++) {
      underscores = document.createElement('li');
      underscores.setAttribute('class', 'boxes');
      guesses.push(underscores);
      underlineHelp.appendChild(underscores);
      character = document.createElement('span');
      character.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hangmanWord[i]));
      character.classList.add('hidden');
      underscores.appendChild(character);
    }
}
```

```css
 .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    ul {
      display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .boxes {
      font-size: 1.6em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 10px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid black;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="hold"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thank you! It is very logical and clarifies my misconception of textNode properties. Cheers!